# Outlook Forms: Recipient does not receive form, only message body //How to store form's data in an email?

Tags: vba, forms, email, outlook

I am currently trying to create a form in Outlook. I want to be able to send this form to different people so that they can make changes to the form and send those changes back to me as a response.

I have a published form in the meantime. My current problem: The recipient does not see the form until he "undocks" the email from the Outlook app and the changes made there are not transmitted to me; I just get an empty form. How or where can I save this data that the recipients enter? I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The form definition includes all the fields and the code that you add to the form. As a general rule, publish the form definition to a forms library instead of sending the form definition with the item. If you cannot publish your form to a forms library, you can select the `Send form definition with item` check box on the `Properties` page so that other users can see the form pages when they receive items that are composed by using the form.

Forms that you only intend to use once and not publish are referred to as `one-off forms`. Because of security concerns with `one-off forms`, users might not see the form correctly when they open items sent to them with a one-off form. In this case, sending the form definition with the `one-off form` provides the necessary information required to display the form correctly for the users.

To change how users reply to your form, click the `Actions page`. The `Actions page` lists the default `Reply forms` that are available. You can also add your own custom `Reply forms`. For example, forms based on a new email message have built-in `Reply`, `Reply to All`, `Forward`, and `Reply to Folder` forms. When users receive your form, the form contains buttons and menu commands so that users can respond to the form. You can disable some or all of these default forms and set attributes that define how these Reply forms appear.

Read more about that in the [Create an Outlook Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/outlook-forms/create-an-outlook-form) section of MSDN.